# Sending parameter with POST requests ,when content-type is multipart/form-data

Tags: post, jmeter

I am new to JMeter. I am trying to create a test plan ,one of the requests is a POST request containing some parameter, the content type in the request header is  Multipart/Form-data.

I am copying the headers/parameters from fiddler because the HTTP proxy recorder is not working.

Please see the image for the current settings I have.I am not able to get the required response using it.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

As per [HTTP Request Sampler Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

> **Use multipart/form-data for HTTP POST**
>
> Use a multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded post request

So all you need to do is:

1. Tick "Use multipart/form-data for POST" box
2. Remove all `Content-Disposition" lines

[image: Multipart Form Data]

[image: Multipart request]

In regards to "proxy recorder not working", I have never experienced any problems with it so it might be misconfiguration or something like this. Some people find [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) easier to use.

Comment: Hi , I removed all content disposition lines from the parameter list . But stillwhen I see it in the result tree ,there is just one single row called form ,the value for which is buy-now
--mJ4HlsETQ6hR_VBYfkXo-xnY5nZAgA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="prod_id"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
and it continues like this for other fields,but they are all in the same row

Answer (score -1):

Instead of copying the content-disposition etc, just send the parameters with name and you should be good. You are expected to send form data and it's value.
ideally it should look like, name should be just 'form' and it's value as 'buy-now'.

I would suggest you compare the requests that you are sending using developer tools and the request you are sending using JMeter, it will help you debug this quicker.

I hope it helps.

Comment: It didnt work,in the result tree ,all the parameter are coming in one line instead of a tabular format [the way they come without multipart on]