# How to send application/json and application/pdf with a single post request, in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to send the following post request. Our developer keeps the JSON code in the model. in this case, I have to send both an upload pdf and the model.

```
------WebKitFormBoundarytNDCqGrEFjFTUxGJ

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model"; filename="blob"

Content-Type: application/json

------WebKitFormBoundarytNDCqGrEFjFTUxGJ

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="LineChart1523101530916.pdf"

Content-Type: application/pdf

------WebKitFormBoundarytNDCqGrEFjFTUxGJ--
```

Comment: Use multi-form post, it's the same question as this: [Sending parameter with POST requests ,when content-type is multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513267/sending-parameter-with-post-requests-when-content-type-is-multipart-form-data)

Comment: Thanks, for replay, but no this not same as you mention. Here server will not accept parameter data. it will accept a post request which has model and .pdf file at the same request.  model means an object which keeps JSON in it.

Comment: The fragment you show, and what you want (a "post request which has model and .pdf file at the same request") is called a **multipart request**, and the solution to question I posted explains exactly how to set it up. Maybe then read a more detailed article on the topic: https://dzone.com/articles/testing-rest-api-file-uploads-in-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

You can send exactly what you want using [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) plugin

Click Add -> jp@gc - HTTP Raw Request

Paste your request as is in Request Data field and it'll be sent as is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For [multipart](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) requests each [Content-Disposition](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) section can have its own [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) so you can build your request like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarytNDCqGrEFjFTUxGJ

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model"; filename="blob"

Content-Type: application/json

------WebKitFormBoundarytNDCqGrEFjFTUxGJ

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="LineChart1523101530916.pdf"

Content-Type: application/pdf

------WebKitFormBoundarytNDCqGrEFjFTUxGJ--
```

directly in the [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) body data tab.

Also make sure to add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and set [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) to something like:

```
multipart/related;boundary=---WebKitFormBoundarytNDCqGrEFjFTUxGJ
```

Check out [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details if needed.

Be super careful as in case of manual multipart requests building every single space or line brake matters and may ruin your test.